# Problems with Javascript radio button alerts

Tags: javascript, radio-button, alert

I need an alert to show when none of the radio buttons have been selected.

Html code:

```
<tr>
<td><input id="Radio1" name="delivery" value="M" type="radio">M</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="Radio2" name="delivery" value="P" type="radio">P</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="Radio3" name="delivery" value="S" type="radio">S</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
        deliveryChecked = ""
    for (i = 0; i < f.deliveryChecked; i++) {
        if (f.deliveryChecked[i].checked) {
            deliveryChecked = f.delivery[i].value
            break
        }
    }

          if (deliveryChecked == "") {
            alert("You did not make a delivery selection!")
        return false
    }
```

Comment: What's "f"?  What do you expect "f.deliveryChecked" to be?

Comment: Trap the next user-generated event (usally clicking a submit button), and check if no radio buttons selected. The key is: bind an event handler to the Submit (or Next / Continue / Go / Whatever) button

Comment: Oh - it looks like you've just got a typo - "f.deliveryChecked" should just be "f.delivery".

Comment: This appears to be a simple typographic error.

Comment: @Pointy 

f = document.jonsForm

    <form name="jonsForm" method="get" action="(Removed for     confidentiality)" onsubmit="return validate ()">

Comment: @user1990577 thb im a beginner w/ javascript so im having problems understanding your code. I replaced your code with mine but it is not working. It just sends me through to my form action without an alert.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <input id="Radio1" name="delivery" value="M" type="radio" />
    <input id="Radio2" name="delivery" value="P" type="radio" />
    <input id="Radio3" name="delivery" value="S" type="radio" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validate(frm){
    var atLeastOneChecked=false;
    [].forEach.call(frm.delivery,function(input){
        atLeastOneChecked=atLeastOneChecked?
            true
                :
            input.checked;
    });
    if(!atLeastOneChecked){
        alert("You did not make a delivery selection!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```